# Codility test: split sms messages into smaller messages of max K characters

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on this Codility challenge:

> You have a long piece of text, and you want to send it to your friend as a series of SMS messages. Your text consists of English letters (uppercase and lowercase) and spaces. The text doesn't contain any leading spaces at the beginning or trailing spaces at the end. There are no two consecutive spaces in the text. One proper SMS can contain at most K characters. If the text is longer, it needs to be split into parts. Each part should be sent in a separate message that fulfills the maximum length requirement. Text may not be split within words. The order of the words and the messages can't change, so that we can later concatenate the resulting messages to retrieve the original text. Spaces at the start and end of all messages are removed, and thus are not accounted for in the overall message length.
>
> The goal is to count the number of SMS messages needed to accommodate the whole text, keeping the length of each message less than or equal to K. The total number of SMS messages must be kept to a minimum, however; it would not be acceptable, for example, to take the wasteful approach of programmatically sending one SMS for each word in the original text!
>
> Write a function: public func solution(_ S: String, _ K: Int) -> Int that, given a string S representing the text that needs to be split and an integer K that is equal to the maximum possible message length, returns the number of SMS messages needed.
>
> For instance, given string S="SMS messages are really short" and K = 12, your function should return 3. You could split this text into proper messages as follows: "SMS" "messages are" "really short"
>
> If it's impossible to split text into proper SMS messages, your function should return −1. Assume that: K is an integer within the range [1..500]; S is a non-empty string containing at most 500 characters: only letters and spaces, there are no spaces at the beginning and at the end of S; also there can't be two or more consecutive spaces in S.

I am sure that I have covered all the corner cases but the test result is showing that only 5 out of 8 test cases are correct. What am I missing in my code?

My code:

```
    public static int solution (String S, int K) {
        String[] words = S.split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String currentWord = "";
        int linesCount = 1;
        boolean isFirst = true;

        for (String word: words) {
            if (word.length() > K) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        for (String word: words) {
            if (currentWord.length() + word.length() + 1 > K) {
                sb.append(currentWord).append("\n");
                linesCount++;
                currentWord = word;
            } else {
                if (isFirst) {
                    currentWord += word;
                    isFirst = false;
                } else {
                    currentWord += " " + word;
                }
            }
        }
        sb.append(currentWord);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        return linesCount;
    }
```

I have tried and tested this code in my IDE, with all test cases that I can think of, and they all pass.

However, it does not pass all Codility tests (which are hidden) and I am wondering what is missing from my code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add your test-cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (currentWord.length() + word.length() + 1 > K) {
```

The addition of 1 in this expression accounts for the space separator, but in case we are in the first iteration of the loop, then no space should be accounted for. So if your test case has a first word (`word.length()`) that has exactly K characters, then this `if` condition will be true, while in fact we should not decide to move that word to the second SMS.

The following test case should return 2, but your code will return 3:

```
solution('ab cd', 2);
```

The correction could be this:

```
if (currentWord.length() + word.length() + (isFirst ? 0 : 1) > K) {
```

#### Remark

It is not necessary to actually collect the chunked strings. You can suffice with just counting the lines without doing any string manipulation.

For instance:

```
    public static int solution(String S, int K) {
        int i = 0;
        int linesCount = 1;
        while (i + K < S.length()) { // while a split is needed
            linesCount++;
            // Find index where next chunk will start
            int j = S.lastIndexOf(' ', i + K) + 1;
            if (i == j) { // Word is too long
                return -1;
            }
            i = j;
        }
        return linesCount;
    }
```